# jQuery scrollTop animation weird and uncontrollable easing

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use jQuery scrollTop animation to scroll to a specific target. But for some reason, no matter what easing i use, it starts very slow and then speeds up. It just looks very odd and ugly.

Additionally, it stops the id "Beauty-target" like planned when it is on top of the screen, but stops the "Fashion-target" , "Artists-target" and "Actors-target" when they are on the bottom of the screen.

To scroll you need to click the "Beauty", "Fashion", "Artists" or "Actors" svg under der "Preise" banner. I used Wordpress and the twenty-tweny theme. The problem occurs on the following website: https:anna-samlidou.com/example

To scroll, I use the same function i use all the time:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        console.log("scroll function started");
    
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = jQuery(target);
    
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
            console.log("scroll function finished");
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

After some investigation i found out that when i remove the

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

from the header.php file, the scrolling works as intended. Also the Website looks very broke.
So i used

```
<?php wp_deregister_script('jquery'); ?>
```

to remove just the jQuery. Which didn't have the same effect, the scrolling was still buggy.
I also installed the Plug In "Remove jQuery Migrate", which didn't help as well.

So which part of the wp_head() function causes this issue? Or how else can i fix this scrolling-issue?

Best regards and thanks a lot in advance,
AlphaLeviathan

**HOW TO FIX:** Thank you @SaschaM78

To fix the problem of the odd animation, i added jQuery with noConflict() like this:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://anna-samlidou.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(document).ready(function(){
            j('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                console.log("scroll function started");

                var target = this.hash;
                var $target = j(target);

                j('html, body').animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuad', function () {
                    console.log("scroll function finished");
                    window.location.hash = target;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In Safari and Firefox this worked fine, but to make it work in Google Chrome i had to unset the scroll-behavior of the html, because it conflicted with the animation.

```
html{scroll-behavior:unset;}
```

The Problem of scrolling to the wrong position was caused by not properly clearing float and with this, messing up the structure. Adding the following html code after every section solved the problem:

```
<br style="clear:both;>
```

All Credits go to @SaschaM78

Comment: Try replacing 'swing' with 'linear' in your call to `.animate()`

Comment: @Luke I already did and just did it again. It's still the same animation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to add your JQuery 3.5.1 version with `var j = jQuery.noConflict()`; and calling `j('a[href^="#"]').on('click', ...);` instead. The Wordpress JQuery version is really old (1.12) and this will definitely cause incompatibilities and issues when mixed.

The issue with the scrolling to the wrong position is caused by not properly clearing floated elements in your `<div class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt">...</div>` containers. The first element has no floated elements in the DOM in front of it and its position is therefor calculated correctly. All headings following this one will have an incorrect position due to the `float:left;` on the `<div class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt-preise-karte ...">...</div>` which are not cleared.

A cleared block would look like this (without showing the inner contains of the three columns:

```
<div class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt">
    <h2 class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt-titel" id="Actors-Target">Actors Shootings</h2>
    <div class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt-preise-container">
      <div class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt-preise-karte preis-karte-links">...</div>

      <div class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt-preise-karte preis-karte-mitte">...</div>
      <div class="preise-kategorien-abschnitt-preise-karte preis-karte-rechts">...</div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved the issue with the wrong positioning of the 3 problematic containers! Thank you for that! But i am still struggeling with the weird animation. I added the following code in the header.php file after wp_head() gets called: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://anna-samlidou.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> and followed immediatly by <script>var j = jQuery.noConflict(); j(document).ready(function()...etc.</script>. The eventlistener shows the onclick function, but the animation is still odd. Any ideas why? Did i add jQuery.noConflict() correctly?

Comment: @AlphaLeviathan problem is that you have two click listeners attached, one inline in line 94, the other in "Anna_Samlidou_Vitals.js" in line 240 :-)

Comment: @SachaM78 I removed the code from the "Anna_Samlidou_Vitals.js" file. If you clear the cache you should see the updated file. But the odd animation persists.

Comment: Very good point, the animation works in Safari as well. So it most likely is a Chrome problem. Firefox seems to struggle with all the svg files, but i did not work on cross-browser compatibility at all yet. My biggest concern is how to fix the animation for Google Chrome as well :/

Comment: @AlphaLeviathan Found the issue: the CSS rule `scroll-behavior: smooth;` in your `body {}` CSS causes Chrome to mess up the animation. Simply remove the rule and the animation will work just fine in Chrome as well.

Comment: @AlphaLeviathan great to hear! Would you be so kind and mark my answer as solution so the question does not remain open? And I would recommend to check the styling in Firefox as well and either add a "back to top" link below the boxes or change your navigation to stick to the top so people don't have to scroll too much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217386/discussion-between-alphaleviathan-and-sascham78).